# Can you consider a directed graph the discretization of a 2-manifold equipped with a vector field?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, manifolds

Can you consider a directed graph the discretization of a 2-manifold equipped with a vector field?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't a graph a 1-dimensional structure? Or don't you want to discretize the 2-dimensional information of your 2-manifold?

Comment: I'm sort of thinking of it in the reverse direction- I don't know what the opposite of discretization is. I guess analogous to a graph embedding.

Comment: For what purpose? (And what is the vector field? I don't see a distinguished choice of direction to flow at a particular vertex.)